# Submit confirmation via Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to have a Submit Modal Confirmation But I have failed to do it correctly.

Here is my JS:

```
function warning(){

      $('#ModalSubmitCart').modal('show');
      var yes = document.getElementById('confirm').value;

      if (yes == 'yes') {
      return true; 
      } 
      else {
      return false;
      } 
}
```

part of my modal:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm" value="yes">Yes</button>
</div>
```

my form

```
<form onSubmit="return warning()" method="POST" action="submitcart.php">
```

I wanted to have something like confirm() but in a Modal form.

Comment: put a fiddle and ill help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct callback functions for the bootstrap `modal`.

I have done a slight hack here.

**What I have done:**

- Added a class to both the buttons on the modal.
- Attached a click callback handler for the buttons & verify by the `text`of the button whether a `close` button is or `yes` button .

**JS Code:**

```
$(function () {
  $('#show').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked');
    warning();
  });

  $('.buttons').on('click', function () {
    var yes = $(this).text();
    if (yes === 'Yes') {
        console.log('yes');
        //return true;
    } else {
        console.log('close');
        //return false;
    }
 });
});

function warning() {
   $('#ModalSubmitCart').modal('show', function (data) {
      console.log('data:' + data);
   });
}
```

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/wccqyzej/**

Comment: Hi. Appreciate it. But... how can I submit the form?

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. Thanks a lot man.  `$("#form_order").submit(); `.

Comment: Glad that was helpful, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your modal in a `FORM` and use a submit button, as you're doing.

```
<form action="/echo/html/" method="POST" name="modalForm" id="modalForm">
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content panel-warning">
        <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and use jQuery to intercept the `submit` event.

```
$('#modalForm').on('submit', function(e){
    if (!confirm('are you sure?'))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can see how it works in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/5anznjyn/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this way your jquery code

```
function warning(){

    $('#ModalSubmitCart').modal('show');
    var yes = $('#confirm').attr("value");

    if (yes == 'yes') {
        return true; 
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```